# Update Pivot Table Source VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to update the Data Source of a pivot table but when I run the makro I get following error:

> The PivotTable field is not a valid. To create a Pivottable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns...

`DataArea = "Log Defects!$A$3:$L$10000"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTablePriority").SourceData = DataArea`

The Pivot Table name is correct! 
The Data Area is copyied from excel (when I click on the pivot table and can select the data source) so the selection should be correct.

Comment: Make sure that the data have headers.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with headers? Just the first row containing the headlines of the column?

Comment: Hey @Michael, I think your understanding of comment is correct... Headers being the first row of a data "block" containing the column names. Are those names in row 3 of the 'Log Defects' sheet?

Comment: AND typing that last comment might have given me a lead on the problem. It seems you don't have single quotes around `Log Defects`... When I make a pivot table on my local computer, if the data is on a sheet that has spaces in the name I need single quotes, meaning that line should say `DataArea = "'Log Defects'!$A$3:$L$10000"`

Comment: Hi, I think your hint with the quotes is correct but it still doesn't work. And yes. Those names are in row 3 of the 'log defects' sheet.
 `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTablePriority").SourceData = "'Log Defects'!$A$3:$L$10000"` Doesn't work :/

Comment: BIRDS VIEW: Try `Log_Defects!$A$3:$L$10000` OR `[YOURWORKBOOKNAME.xlsm]Log Defects!R3C1:R10000C12` OR `[YOURWORKBOOKNAME.xlsm]Log_Defects!R3C1:R10000C12`

Comment: I think the 2nd one should work

Comment: @SiddharthRout is correct. It uses R1C1 reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dim WSname as String
        WSname= "Log Defects"
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTablePriority").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        WSname & "!R3C1:R10000C12", Version:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

Note WSname is in no quotes. also to change the scaling R=row so its row 3 to 10000 and C= column so 1 to 12 or column A to L.